# API to get G+ community Post

Tags: google-api, google-plus

I am looking for an API to get all my private community post information. Hope, there is no direct API from Google to do this job. Anyone have any workaround or suggestions to get this information.

Answer (score 0):

The Google+ api is very limited, is read only there is no way to post to Goolge+ soical media website currently.   There is also no way to read from communities on Goolge+

If Google hasn't released an API for this then there is no API for it.